# Access User's Location Once in viewDidAppear Method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, locationmanager

I have two different `UIViewControllers` that need access to the user's `Latitude` and `Longitude`. I only need to access the location once when the view appears. I am currently storing the `LocationManager` in the app delegate, but the `viewDidAppear:` method loads too quickly for the user's location to be found. Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Write your code in `ViewDidLoad` method , it will load at only one time.

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't fire quickly enough. the view appears/loads before the location can be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a shared `LocationManager`. Then `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` after you get a callback.

Here is the code I use:

In your `appDelegate` add the following method:

```
+ (NHAppDelegate *)sharedDelegate
{
    return (NHAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

And make the LocationManager available:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Then in your UIViewController you can do:

```
[NHAppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager.delegate = self;
[[NHAppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then I use the following code to get the location and display it in a UILabel.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self loadPositionWithLocation:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [self loadPositionWithLocation:location];
}

-(void)loadPositionWithLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         if ([placemarks count] > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *thoroughfare = placemark.thoroughfare;
             NSString *subThoroughfare = placemark.subThoroughfare;
             NSString *postalCode = placemark.postalCode;
             NSString *locality = placemark.locality;

             if( thoroughfare == nil )      {  thoroughfare = @"";     }
             if( subThoroughfare == nil )   {  subThoroughfare = @"";  }
             if( postalCode == nil )        {  postalCode = @"";       }
             if( locality == nil )          {  locality = @"";         }

             NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@", thoroughfare, subThoroughfare, postalCode, locality];

             self.positionLabel.text = addressString;

             [[NHAppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
         }
     }];
}
```

Important is the last line `stopUpdatingLocation` so the `LocationManager` only gets called once.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like a typical case where `NSNotification`s are useful.  I believe that CoreLocation does not send notifications.  In that case you'll have to do it yourself.  In AppDelegate.h you define:

```
const string* LocationUpdateNotification  = @"LocationUpdateNotification";
```

Then in the your CoreLocation delegate method in AppDelegate.m you do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNofificationName:LocationUpdateNotification 
                                                        object:self];
});
```

Finally in each of your view controllers:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:MyNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification* note)
    {
        // YOUR LOCATION UPDATE CODE.
    }];
```